# Meaning of attribute value containing prefixed name

Tags: xml

I have the following XML:

```
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="AdvancedVerifyEmailHttpGetIn">
<wsdl:part name="email" type="s:string"/>
<wsdl:part name="timeout" type="s:string"/>
<wsdl:part name="LicenseKey" type="s:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:operation name="AdvancedVerifyEmail">
<wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
This function will verify an email address and also includes the ability to timeout the verification process. The Verification can be slowed down by the email server being verified against. <b>Timeout is in seconds</b> Use a licensekey of 0 for testing <br> NOTE: A timeout error (7) does not mean an email will not go through. You should treat this as a good email address.
</wsdl:documentation>
**<wsdl:input message="tns:AdvancedVerifyEmailHttpGetIn"/**>
<wsdl:output message="tns:AdvancedVerifyEmailHttpGetOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

The highlighted one tag input contains message attribute which has value as "tns:AdvancedVerifyEmailHttpGetIn" which has prefixed namespace.

Could you please help me understand whether this means message declared before is of namespace tns or just its like a message attribute is referring the message and whatever message would be part of that input would be in tns namespace?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the schema you will see that the message attribute has type xs:QName. That basically means it behaves like an element or attribute name: the part before the colon ("tns") is interpreted as a namespace prefix, and the validator checks that this prefix has been properly declared on some outer ancestor element.